# How to remove an image and it's label from a dataset

Tags: python-3.x

When I import a dataset of images and the csv file with the corresponding labels, I made a function to extract every image label. But know I have to remove some images that do not fit specific criteria. Is there a way to remove the corresponding label as well?

This is the function that is used to load the images and the labels

```py
def imp_img():

    dirname = '/s/desk/img/'
    x = np.zeros((1000, 100, 100), dtype=np.float32) 

    for i in range(x.shape[0]):
        img    = Image.open(dirname + 'img_%02d.png' % (i)) 
        img    = np.array(img)
        x[i] = img


    path = '/s/desk/labels_classificatio.csv'    
    labels = pd.read_csv(path, usecols=["category"],
                       sep=";" )
    y = np.array(labels)

    return x, y
```

This is how they are imported

```py
x, y = imp_img()
x = x/255.0
y = y.reshape(y.shape[0], 1)
x.shape, y.shape
```

and now I made for loop to remove the images that are too dark

```py
c =[]
for i in x: 
    if np.sum(i) >= 100:
        c.append(i)
c = np.asarray(c)
```

The problem now is that I have fewer images than I have labels. Is there a way to remove the corresponding label as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for `enumerate`. It lets you loop over an iterable while maintaining a count. Instead of `for i in x` we'll do `for i, img in enumerate(x)` which let us maintain a loop counter `i`. This way you can sbset the labels corresponding to the images that meet your criteria.

code:

```
c = []
c_labels = []
for i, img in enumerate(x): 
    if np.sum(img) >= 100:
        c.append(img)
        c_labels.append(y[i])
c = np.asarray(c) 
c_labels = np.asarray(c_labels)
```